# modify permissions for files created by php script

Tags: php, file-permissions

How (or can) I change the following `php script` so that when it creates a new file, it gives the file `r/w` permission?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['data'])) {
        $data = $_GET['data']  . "\n";
        $ip = $_GET['ip'];
        $ret = file_put_contents('/opt/tomcat7/webapps/servlets/WEB-INF/logs/' . $ip, $data, LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing the lab data file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
        die('no data to process');
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php also be aware of the security issues with passing data directly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [chmod](http://php.net/chmod) function.

For example `chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755)`